# Extracting cell values from excel to xml

Tags: xml, vba, excel

My requirement is to export a row from Excel to XML. For example, if spreadsheet looks like this:

```
MessageID  OriginalField    OriginalCOBO  RevisedCOBOL        ChangeIndicator
I23456I    SDQ              SOURCE        SOURCE-DATA-QUEUE   1
```

Then, I need to create a xml based on `[Change Indicator]=1`.

Column values need to be element tag, not the column header. For example, desired output would be:

```
<I23456I>
<SDQ>
    <COBOLName>SOURCE-DATA-QUEUE</COBOLName>
</SDQ>
</I23456I>
```

`MessageID` and `OriginalField` values will be keep changing and it is not the same for all.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't know if there is more sophisticated way but it is possible to pass values to a text file for which a xml file is a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) VBA object to create your XML nodes and tags iteratively, conditional on the fifth column: `[Change Indicator] = 1`. At the end a pretty print XSLT stylesheet is used to properly line break and indent outputted XML. Do note: a `Root` tag is added for a well-formed XML file:

```
Sub xmlExport()
    ' Add Microsoft XML v6.0 VBA Reference '
    Dim doc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim root As IXMLDOMElement, msgNode As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim orgfldNode As IXMLDOMElement, orgcoboNode As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim i As Long

    ' DECLARE XML DOC OBJECT '
    Set root = doc.createElement("Root")
    doc.appendChild root

    ' WRITE TO XML '
    For i = 2 To Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count

        If Cells(i, 5) = 1 Then

            ' MESSAGE NODE '
            Set msgNode = doc.createElement(Cells(i, 1))
            root.appendChild msgNode

            ' ORIGINAL FIELD NODE '
            Set orgfldNode = doc.createElement(Cells(i, 2))
            msgNode.appendChild orgfldNode

            ' ORIGINAL COBO NODE '
            Set orgcoboNode = doc.createElement("COBOLNAME")
            orgcoboNode.Text = Cells(i, 4)
            orgfldNode.appendChild orgcoboNode
        End If

    Next i

    ' PRETTY PRINT RAW OUTPUT '
    xslDoc.LoadXML "<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & "?>" _
        & "<xsl:stylesheet version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) _
        & "            xmlns:xsl=" & Chr(34) & "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" & Chr(34) & ">" _
        & "<xsl:strip-space elements=" & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & " />" _
        & "<xsl:output method=" & Chr(34) & "xml" & Chr(34) & " indent=" & Chr(34) & "yes" & Chr(34) & "" _
        & "            encoding=" & Chr(34) & "UTF-8" & Chr(34) & "/>" _
        & " <xsl:template match=" & Chr(34) & "node() | @*" & Chr(34) & ">" _
        & "  <xsl:copy>" _
        & "   <xsl:apply-templates select=" & Chr(34) & "node() | @*" & Chr(34) & " />" _
        & "  </xsl:copy>" _
        & " </xsl:template>" _
        & "</xsl:stylesheet>"

    xslDoc.async = False
    doc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Output.xml"

End Sub
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <I23456I>
        <SDQ>
            <COBOLNAME>SOURCE-DATA-QUEUE</COBOLNAME>
        </SDQ>
    </I23456I>
</Root>
```

Comment: I tried with this code and added referenced -Microsoft XML, v6.0 in VBA.

But I am getting error:
Run-time '429': ActiveX component can't create object.

I am using Microsoft excel 2013.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Are you sure you selected v6.0 and not v3.0 under Tools / References in VBE? I also MS Excel 2013 but I use PC, not Mac OS or Linux.

Comment: I have additional requirement :
CASHIN OCCURS 7 TIMES ||  CASH-IN-TABLE  OCCURS 7 TIMES.These 2 are columns values under OriginalCOBO  RevisedCOBOL column header mentioned in question respectively.
Under this there are 3 rows which are repating 7 times.
For e.g.: 
Row1: I23456I    SDQ   SOURCE   SOURCE-DATA-QUEUE   1
Row2: I234562    TES   Cash      Transaction-IN    1
Row3: I23452O    DQW   Cash-out  Transaction-OUT    1

Comment: And my XML should look like this:
<I23456I>
 <SDQ>
  <OccursName>CASH-IN-TABLE</OccursName>
  <OccursFirstField>SDQ</OccursFirstField>
  <OccursLastField>DQW</OccursLastField>
  <OccursTimes>7</OccursTimes>
 </SDQ>
</I23456I>

Comment: Great! Please accept answer if it helped to confirm resolution. As for additional requirement that may be a new question.