# .SaveAs Method or Data Member Not found

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I'm trying to save an XML from Excel conversion into newDoc which is a MSXML2.DOMDocument, however whenever I run my code it highlights .SaveAs and says that the method or data member is not found. I understand that this is because newDoc is not a workbook, but how else would I go around this?

```
xslDoc.async = False
    doc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    Dim Docname As String
    Dim fileSaveName As Variant
    Docname = "123_" & SN.Text
    fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=sItem * Docname, filefilter:="XML Files (*.xml),*xml")
   ' 
    newDoc.SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveName, FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: Maybe you have forgotten - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344105/extracting-cell-values-from-excel-to-xml/37364040 to declare correctly newDoc? `Dim newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60`

Comment: What *is* `newDoc`?

Comment: @VanNg that object doesn't have a `SaveAs` method either, though :)

Comment: Dim newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60 is how I declared newDoc earlier in the document

Comment: Is there any way that I could save it?

Comment: You can use the [`save`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms753769%28v%3dvs.85%29) method of the DOMDocument class (note that the `FileFormat` and `CreateBackup` are not arguments for this method).

Comment: Wait, would this allow me to save it with a specific name as well, or only choose the destination for the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`save`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms753769%28v%3dvs.85%29) method of the DOMDocument class (note that the `FileFormat` and `CreateBackup` are not arguments for this method).

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need to do!